# numberOfSectionsInTableView not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

```
import UIKit

class exploreViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var exploreTableView: UITableView!
    var CELLHEIGHT = 200
    var SECTIONHEADER = "SECTIONHEADER"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        exploreTableView.delegate = self
        exploreTableView.dataSource = self
        exploreTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "answerCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell1")
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return SECTIONHEADER
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.exploreTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath) as! answerCell
        cell.name.text = "222222"
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(CELLHEIGHT)
    }  
}
```

My `numberOfSectionsInTableView` is never called and I can't get 2 sections.

Comment: Because that is not the name of the method. Its name is `numberOfSections(in:)`.

Comment: @matt `numberOfSections(in:tableView)` ?

Comment: @OnurTuna Distinguish name from declaration.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From your code, I believe you are using Swift3. Then, the following are delegate and datasource methods for UITableView in Swift3

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}
```

As you can see, your numberOfSections function's syntax is wrong.That is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually due to access level resolution. When we don't specify the "public" ourselves, the compiler resolves it as to be some privately implemented function and even warns that it nearly matches a public function. If one ignores this then it neglects this function and rather calls the default implementation. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -2):

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }